# Reducing speed of instances that touch my object

Tags: gml

-in my collision event against the asteroid, when an asteroid touches the object, all of them slow down when i want only the ones inside the object to be slowed down.

```
//object collision with asteroid/as1
with instance_place(x, y,as1) {
              as1.speed=1;
              }
```

the asteroids have a spawner that spawns 250 of  them, and have random movement speeds, directions if it has anything to do with this

Comment: You really need to give more general information and more code to explain your problem. As it is, it is impossible to understand your question, let alone answer it.

Comment: Julian, Just search "instance_place" in the yoyogames doc and you will see that this function returns a boolean, and it is clearly not what he wants with the "with" construction :)

Answer (score 0):

The instance_place function returns a boolean (0 or 1) if there is an "as1" object at (x,y). Here, when you touch an asteroid, you say "with 1", which I think means with every object.

But what you want to do is give "with" the unique ID of the object you touch. So the function to use is "instance_position".
Official documentation : https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20functions/instance_position.html

Your code should look like :

```
//object collision with asteroid/as1
with instance_position(x, y,as1) {
              as1.speed=1;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

"instance_place" returns a boolean (true/false)
you can use "instance_position" instead, which returns a unique ID of the object.
but there is a simpler way:

instead of:

```
with instance_place(x, y,as1) {
    as1.speed=1;
}
```

just use:

```
other.speed=1;
```

its much simpler (:

"other" refers to the other object in the collision event